# Add a side vertical rule

Tags: beamer, templates

I would add a simple vertical rule with a logo and the page number (as in the example) to a default beamer template.

Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the sidebar template to fit your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,left,width=1cm]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!20!white,fg=white}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][.98\paperheight][t]{1cm}%
        \vskip1.5em%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
        \vfill      
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{sidebar}
        \insertframenumber
        \vskip1.5em%
    \end{minipage}
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]